# How can I check if the browser support HTML5 file upload (FormData object)?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, safari, html5-video, opera

How can I check if the browser support HTML5 file upload (FormData object)?

```
var fd = new FormData();
```

Following the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712427/html5-file-upload-feature-detections-in-browser), but the code does not return correct answer about the browser,

```
window.onload = function()
{
 if (!!window.FileReader)
 {
  alert('supported');
 }
 else
 {
  alert('not supported');
 }
}


Firefox - supported
Chrome - supported
Opera - supported
Safari - not supported
IE9 - not supported
```

But the correct browser support should be,

```
Firefox - supported
Chrome - supported
Opera - not supported
Safari - supported
IE9 - not supported
```

I have tested the html 5 file upload on **Opera** and it is **not** working for sure.

I am sure that **safari**  supports html 5 file upload.

Answer (score 70):

Try `if( window.FormData === undefined )` or `if( window.FormData !== undefined )`.

Comment: +1, in IE8/IE9 `( window.FormData === undefined )` returns true and in IE10, it returns false.

Comment: Should probably use `typeof`, since `undefined` is not a keyword in some browsers. (e.g. I can say `var undefined = window.FormData`)

Comment: So, with typeof, "if( typeof( window.FormData ) == 'undefined' )", right?

Comment: @DCShannon no need for the parens: `if(typeof window.FormData === 'undefined')`

Comment: @Koen Just because they're optional doesn't mean they're forbidden. I prefer to use the parentheses.

Comment: I didn't say that they're forbidden. But do you write `+`, `-` and other "unary operators" with parentheses too? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference#Unary_operators

Answer (score 11):

From
http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/7/30/html5-powered-ajax-file-uploads

```
function supportAjaxUploadProgressEvents() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return !! (xhr && ('upload' in xhr) && ('onprogress' in xhr.upload));
};
```

As FormData, the ability to send() one, and the upload property (and its onprogress event) are all part of XMLHttpRequest level 2, you can test for .upload to see if you've got a level 2.  I don't have a Mac handy, but the function (sadly, but correctly) returns false for Opera 11.50 (and true for Firefox 4).

Answer (score 7):

```
  function supportFormData() {
     return !! window.FormData;
  }
```

Source: https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata/

Answer (score 3):

This is the one-liner I use to check if the browser supports FormData and upload progress, in jQuery:

```
 var xhr2 = !! ( window.FormData && ("upload" in ($.ajaxSettings.xhr()) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could may be use the workaround provided by this library.
https://github.com/francois2metz/html5-formdata

Answer (score 1):

On Safari 5.1.7 , Firefox <6, Opera < 12.14 form data is suported but it is buggy.

- Safari will return file size 0

  Opera does not support append method    of form data

  firefox <6 does not work correctly

Answer (score -3):

You need to check if the browser supports the HTML5 file API. I do that by checking if the FileReader function is set, if it’s not set it means that the browser won’t support the file API.

```
// Check if window.fileReader exists to make sure the browser supports file uploads
if (typeof(window.FileReader) == 'undefined') 
    {
        alert'Browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!');
    }
```

Comment: This code checks for the FileReader object, which is different than the FormData object.