# How to detect directory select capability in browsers?

Tags: html, file-upload, html5-filesystem

I am trying to find out if browser has ability to select folders, not just multiple files. Current Chrome supports this (example: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/demos/upload_directory/index.html).

Apparently, it works in Chrome when `<input type="file" />` has `webkitdirectory` attribute. But how can I test if browser is actually capable of selecting folders and iterating through files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if the browser support HTML5 file upload (FormData object)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296426/how-can-i-check-if-the-browser-support-html5-file-upload-formdata-object)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. As far as I know, only Chrome supports webkitdirectory (or the future directory attribute) while other browsers currently support HTML5 File API. There is a need for such a test, as the Chrome `<input type="file" webkitdirectory />` allows _only_ folders to be selected, not files or folders.

Comment: Hey @GeoffreyBooth -- I already wrote Modernizr plugin for this.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this is a solution for your problem:

```
function isInputDirSupported() {
    var tmpInput = document.createElement('input');
    if ('webkitdirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'mozdirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'odirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'msdirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'directory' in tmpInput) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is pretty much what we did in a custom Modernizr test.

Comment: This return true in Android Chrome, but its input length will not change after selected this file.