# How can I check if the browser support webkitdirectory?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit, multifile-uploader

I am using Google Chrome's folder upload feature in my project, described here:
[How do I use Google Chrome 11's Upload Folder feature in my own code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5826286/3477084)

I have a button that trigger an input field when be clicked. My question is How can I check if the browser support webkitdirectory or not? so I can hide my button or alert the user to use chrome for this service.

```
<button>Upload Folder</button>
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple webkitdirectory>

<script>
  $("button").click(function(e) {
    /* TODO: Detect webkitdirectory support */
    if(webkitdirectory)
      $('input').trigger('click');
    else
      alert('Use Chrome!');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You could try Modernizr. Looks like they implemented a check for this a couple of years ago https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/674 Failing that, check out the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169585/how-to-detect-directory-select-capability-in-browsers

Comment: I used https://github.com/DamonOehlman/detect-browser I'm not the creator, but I enjoy it because it's lightweight and does exactly what you're looking for. When used in combination with https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-directory makes things pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Modernizer](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/6d56d814b9682843313b16060adb25a58d83a317/feature-detects/input/fileinputdirectory.js) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14968930/3477084) I could use this function to detect if directory select is supported:

```js
function testFileInputDirectory() {
    var elem = document.createElement('input'),
    dir = 'directory',
    domPrefixes = [ "", "moz", "o", "ms", "webkit" ],
    prefix;
    
    elem.type = 'file';
    
    for (prefix in domPrefixes) {
      if (domPrefixes[prefix] + dir in elem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To see if **webkitdirectory** is supported, check for the property in the input element:

```
webkitdirectorySupported(){
  return 'webkitdirectory' in document.createElement('input')
}
```

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the reason for the downvote of this answer. The Modernizer approach seems excessively defensive and encourages the idea of browser-specific prefixes, especially since I have never encountered any other version than `webkitdirectory` so far.

In any case, for defensive coding, I would simply add the check for `directory` on this answer and keep it a one-liner. Much cleaner.