# Using Modernizr to detect drag and drop

Tags: html

I have a section of a website that relies on drag and drop in HTML5.  I would like the site to alert the user on the home page whether their browser supports it and I have tried to use Modernizr but without success.

I have used the modernizr site to create a custom file (the one included in this instance has all HTML5 options selected) but it does nothing.  I have tried creating several but with no joy.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.75231.js"></script>
<script>

   if(Modernizr.draganddrop){
      alert("Your browser supports drag and drop!!");
   }else{
      alert("Sorry, browser does not support drag and drop!");
   }

</script>

</head>

<body>
Some text
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Just to update, I have created the modernizr file again to include all of the CSS options and now it detects every browser including ie 7 as drag and drop compatible

```
js/modernizr.custom.18141.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
if(Modernizr.draganddrop)
```

to

```
if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop)
```

and then it worked fine

Comment: Check this answer too - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19551180/28321 Modernizr 2.6.x has test for filereader under non-core detects

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit trickier.  iOS7 reports that it supports both FileReader and draganddrop pictures uploading.  Since I was looking for a more general file upload that I couldn't do with iOS, I needed another answer.

Modernizr issue 57 at [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/57) talks about the issue.  Now with windows 8 and both touch and mouse, its tricky.  There's code in the middle by chriskeeble that I used successfully.  It relies on Modernizr and agent detection.

Answer (score 0):

**Modernizr** returns a false-positive for Drag and Drop in **Windows-Safari v5.1.7** (latest -- and now looking to be the final version!). This is not surprising, since (I am told) previous versions (v5.0.x) had functional drag & drop infrastructure (which Modernizr detects). Modernizr will not easily discover an event misfire bug (which suggests to me that a correct detection scheme may need to incorporate some url database query).

> Note: Safari v5.1.7 does not fire an ondrop event (instead, it tends to
>   misfire a false ondragleave event, which almost certainly undermines
>   any code-redeemable effort to workaround this bug. If you turn to jquery to fix one version of one browser, you may as well surrender javascript without it.

I had hoped (against all hope) that **Modernizr** detection *might* enable some clever remedy, but with apple pulling support from Windows Safari (blunder, imho), I'm left wondering why the present infrastructure compels developers to support defective products;  the proper remedy is a full recall of the version, and the responsibility of developers is to alert users when they are using a version of a browser with a known defect -- even if that's every browser (note: should every version of every browser prove defective, demand a better specification).