# jquery ui Drag and drop feature detection

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, browser-feature-detection

I am using jQuery UI drag and drop on my website. I gather mobile devices generally do not support this functionality, so what is the simplest way to detect whether this feature will work or not, to provide an alternative in case it does not.

Note: I prefer feature detection over browser detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library as posted here [Using Modernizr to detect drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224266/using-modernizr-to-detect-drag-and-drop)

Comment: Doesn't work.  Modernizr is showing I have drag and drop capability, but jQueryUI drag and drop is not working.

Is there a difference between dragging and dropping files (which I suspect is what Modernizr is looking for) and dragging and dropping divs (which is what I need)?