# Which browser features should be tested to pick the correct file upload plugin?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, modernizr

We have wrapped the flash-based Uploadify and the HTML5 based UploadiFive uploaders together in a new plugin, so that we don't have to supply two sets of options all the time.

This hides all the nasty name and feature changes they made between the two plugin versions (why oh why did they not make the settings compatible or wrap both controls themselves???).

The problem we had was detecting when to use each uploader version. If we just detect `Modernizr.canvas` it tries to use the HTML5 uploader on IE9 (which has a canvas but is not HTML5 as far as file uploading goes).

What are the most accurate browser features to test for in this specific instance?

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer: [How to determine presence of HTML5 drag'n'drop file upload API (like the one from FF3.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311887/how-to-determine-presence-of-html5-dragndrop-file-upload-api-like-the-one-fro) which does the trick nicely (not the main answer but one of the followups):

```
if (!!window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop) {
  // sexy drag and drop action
} else {
  // no drag and drop support available :(
}
```